How to fix encoding Russian language issue
Cannot map data properly
Data exactly in FoxPro has received well
enter image description here
var list = new List<IdStringName>();
using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Codepage=1252;Data Source=C:\Users\boris\Documents\MyOwnDbfs\data1.dbc"))
{
    dbConnection.Open();
    using (IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from ToExportFromFoxProToCSharpTest";
        using (IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new IdStringName
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    StringName = reader.GetString(1)
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.StringName}\t{item.Id}");
}

Console.ReadLine();

Encoding issue
With english letters works well

Thanks.
I've tried to use 1252, 1251, 1250, 850 and 866 (in connection string) right now, but it didn't work.
Maybe you have more ideas?

This data (DBFs) was created not by me.
So I fixed it like this.
I've deleted local FoxPro instance and do this:
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Dapper;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        IEnumerable<string> strings;

        using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\boris\\Documents\\DBFs;Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Codepage=1252;"))
        {
            strings = await oleDbConnection.QueryAsync<string>("SELECT name FROM spisok");
        }

        foreach (string s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}

Thanks everybody who tried to help
